# Acceder a una variable de un método desde otro método en un controlador de Laravel

Tags: php

Me pueden ayudar con mi duda si hay forma de acceder a la variable que esta en otro método en un controlador de laravel, por favor.

```
public function calculo1(){
    $variable_a_la_que_quiero_acceder = 5;
    return view('vista1', compact('variable_a_la_que_quiero_acceder'));
}

public function calculo2(){
    $x = 2;
    $resultado = $variable_a_la_que_quiero_acceder + $x;
    
    return view('vista2', compact('resultado'));

}
```

Comment: ¿Has intentado algo al respecto?, ¿ese código te da algún error?

Comment: Porque no simplemente haces que la primera funcion retorne ese valor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En Laravel nadie te impide tener variables de clase ni métodos que no devuelvan una vista, es decir, podrías hacer algo así:

```php
class ControllerController extends Controller {

    private $variable_a_la_que_quiero_acceder;

    public function __construct()
    {
        // Si necesitas inicializar la variable:
        $this->variable_a_la_que_quiero_acceder = valorDeDondeSea();
    }

        public function calculo1(){
        $variable = $this->variable_a_la_que_quiero_acceder;
        return view('vista1', compact('variable'));
    }

    public function calculo2(){
        $x = 2;
        $resultado = $this->variable_a_la_que_quiero_acceder + $x;
        return view('vista2', compact('resultado'));

    }

}
```

De esta manera podrás acceder a la variable en tantos métodos como necesites, y si el valor va a ser siempre el mismo, donde la declaras puedes ponerle el valor directamente `private $variable_a_la_que_quiero_acceder = 5;`.

---

Como correctamente menciona @BetaM en su comentario, creo que el problema aquí está en una falta de base de programación orientada a objetos (POO) en PHP. En Laravel se hace uso extensivo de la POO así que te recomiendo encarecidamente que intentes adquirir una buena base antes de continuar usando Laravel, puesto que si no, no entenderás la mitad de lo que haces y tendrás un montón de dudas como esta. Para empezar, el curso **GRATUITO** de [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_oop_what_is.asp) de php oop está muy bien, y te enseñará lo básico para que puedas manejarte.

Comment: Mas que *en Laravel*, esto es mas orientado a PHP ¿no?, lo digo por que la pregunta me parece mas orientada a que el OP no sabe identificar como declarar las propiedades de una clase y como usarlas dentro de métodos

Comment: Efectivamente, me refería a que en Laravel se puede escribir *php normal*. Como bien indicas, parece ser una carencia de base en cuanto a programación orientada a objetos en php. Sería bueno que repasase un poquito de teoría :)

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo haría de esta forma:

```
    public function calculo1(){
        $variable_a_la_que_quiero_acceder = 5;
        return $variable_a_la_que_quiero_acceder;
    }
    
    public function calculo2(){
        $x = 2;
        $variable_a_la_que_quiero_acceder = $this->calculo1();
        $resultado = $variable_a_la_que_quiero_acceder + $x;
        return view('vista', compact('resultado','variable_a_la_que_quiero_acceder'));
    }
```

Espero te funcione.

Comment: Muchas gracias si funciono solo que también necesito pasarla a la vista: public function calculo1(){
    $variable_a_la_que_quiero_acceder = 5; return view('vista', compact('variable_a_la_que_quiero_acceder'));
}      -------------   En ese caso como le podría hacer?

Comment: Quieres pasar el retornar el valor de calculo1() en la funcion de calculo2() ??

Comment: Edite la respuesta, si deseas retornar el valor de calculo1 en tu vista entonces pasas el valor de $variable_a_la_que_quiero_acceder en la funcion compact() asi como lo edite arriba

Comment: Ya edite la pregunta a ver si me explique un poco mas.

Comment: Simplemente añade una tercera función que devuelva lo que tú quieres, o utiliza una variable de clase en el controlador